# Rewriting a url with more than one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my urls on a page that has a pagination option and I'm unsure of what string to use because the one i'm currently using isn't working.

**My document structure is below**

- blog-listing.php
- htaccess
- /blog/post.php
- /css/
- /js/
- /images/

**What's already in my htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/archive.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(css)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(perch)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(js)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**The line i've tried to use**

```
RewriteRule ^blog-listing/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog-listing.php?s=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

**The url I'm receiving**

http://mysite(dot)com/blog-listing.php?page=2

**The url I'd like**

http://mysite(dot)com/blog-listing/page-2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple file to manage your url

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all requests not pointing at an actual file to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

https://github.com/ogallardop/blackjack-api/blob/master/src/.htaccess

The framework you're using to pagination will do the rest.